# ajax file upload - asp.net mvc not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

This is a classic problem: uploading a file with ajax. There are several methods which I tried. They all worked in other browsers but not in IE 11. The Requests.Files has 0 elements and the HttpPostedFileBase as the controller action parameter is null.

Here is some sample code:

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(string type, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     //file is null
     // Request.Files -> 0 elements
}

var options = {
        success: function () {
            //alert("success")
        },
        complete: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText)
        },

        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR: unable to upload files");
        }
    };

    $("#logo-form").ajaxForm(options);
    $("#logo-form").submit();
```

}

It works (even in IE) if I just submit the form without ajaxForm or a special $.ajax for the file upload. But I need either one of these because I need to know when the upload finished. It's strange that it's not working in IE 11.

Paul

Comment: This looks like something to do with the ajaxForm plugin, rather than MVC - I've done this in pure JS / jQuery coupled with MVC 4/5 and has worked fine in IE11.

Comment: Are you using standard input file tag or any other way to provide file on client side?
Can you attach client side form code?

Comment: Hi Paul, have you been able to resolve this issue? I am running into this issue now where dropzone does not seem to call my SaveUploadedFile action when I run with IE 11. Any idea how to fix this?